# SFAuthenticationManager deprecated in 6.0

Tags: ios, salesforce, native, hybrid-mobile-app, salesforce-ios-sdk

We have a custom salesforce iOS application currently running on `salesforcemobilesdk 5.3.1`. It is a both native and hybrid mixed application. I am planning to update it to the latest but I am finding few decrepency in the library. In v6.0 sdk  `SFAuthenticationManager` is deprecated, but Hybrid sdk still needs `SFAuthenticationManager`. If I use cocoapods or use forceios, it doesn't have `SFAuthenticationManager`. How do I overcome it and is there a document reference where can I refer for using `SFUserAccountManager` instead of `SFAuthenticationManager`? Any guidance on this is much appreciated. Thanks!